# Datagridview Updating

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

How to update the `DataGridView` so that it will effect the changes in database too?
The code which I am trying is:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow myDgrow in dataGridView2.Rows) {
    myCmd = "Update Details set ProjectName='" 
          + myDgrow.Cells["ProjectName"].Value 
          + "', Description = '" 
          + myDgrow.Cells["Description"].Value 
          + "', DateStarted='" 
          + myDgrow.Cells["DateStarted"].Value 
          + "',TeamSize='" 
          + myDgrow.Cells["TeamSize"].Value 
          + "',Manager='" 
          + myDgrow.Cells["Manager"].Value 
          + "'";

    myCmd = "Update Details set Description = '" 
          + myDgrow.Cells["Description"].Value 
          + "', DateStarted='" 
          + myDgrow.Cells["DateStarted"].Value 
          + "',TeamSize='" 
          + myDgrow.Cells["TeamSize"].Value 
          + "',Manager='" 
          + myDgrow.Cells["Manager"].Value 
          + "' where ProjectName='" 
          + myDgrow.Cells["ProjectName"].Value 
          + "'";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectName1", myDgrow.Cells["ProjectName"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description1", myDgrow.Cells["Description"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateStarted1", myDgrow.Cells["DateStarted"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamSize1", myDgrow.Cells["TeamSize"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manager1", myDgrow.Cells["Manager"].Value);
    cmd.CommandText = myCmd;

    dataGridView2.Update();

    //cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myCmd = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: call dataGridView2.Update(); after  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); and try again

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataGridView Updating database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459416/datagridview-updating-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this is what you want to do:

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, c))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", myDgrow.Cells["field1"].Value);
    ...

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

where `sql` might look something like:

```
UPDATE table SET field1 = @field1, field2 = @field2 WHERE fieldId = @fieldId
```

and you're going to do that for each iteration inside the `foreach` loop.

I honestly don't know what you're doing in your code because you're setting `myCmd`, back to back, to two different things, and then you're not using it. So I have no idea what SQL the `cmd` object has. So just modify your code to use the structure I put forth and it will work just as expected.

**NOTE:** I don't know if the users are allowed to add to the data grid, but if they are, you'll build a different `sql` because it will need to be an `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

call `dataGridView2.Update();` after `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and try again